# Flashbuilder 4.7 Not linking or indexing folders in a linked source path

Tags: flash-builder

So recently switched machines to a MacBook Air, OSX 10.9.2

Pulled down the project I was working on into a fresh install of Flashbuilder, with AIRSDK version 13

All settings match with other functioning setups from other team members but for some reason for me the project is not linking or indexing folders in a linked source path.

The specific issue is that when in a non-linked source folder, everything works fine, but when editing a file that lies within a linked source folder the programme won't open declarations, content assist doesn't work, etc.

so:

src |
        -> File.as

linked_folder | src |
        -> OtherFile.as

Everything from File.as works 100%, so it can see, interact with, and reference OtherFile.as (with autocompletion, and the rest), as well as all the other files in the linked_folder, and the other linked folders.

From OtherFile.as, when opened in FlashBuilder, it doesn't seem to even open as an as file.  When you open the autocompletion (Ctrl + Space), it shows none of the normal suggestion windows, no "Templates", no "Variables", no "Classes and Interfaces", or anything else.  It just shows an empty suggestion window, with no alternatives.

Have tried everything I can think of, but have never seen this before.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Just incase someone else has this same problem I figured I'd answer my own question.

T'was a rogue capitalization in my project path. 
Basically instead of cloning the project into developer/repos/git/myprojectname I had cloned it to developer/repos/git/Myprojectname

Drove me crazy, but that was the problem.

Comment: If your question/answer have no value for the community (trivial error/typo), you might consider removing them.